# How do I associate an SSID to a device?

Tags: wifi, wireshark, aircrack-ng

In other words I am referring to the `wlan.fc.type_subtype==0x04` filter in Wireshark while using a WiFi adapter in monitor mode.

How can I associate an SSID to an Android device (for example) if that Android device was in the past connected to that specific SSID?

Is there any tool to do that?

Can I output it in terminal (without using Wireshark)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes this is possible. Devices will send probes for any network currently in their wifi configuration, **which for most users are all the networks they have signed on to in the past**. So your home network for example is in the config of your mobile and your mobile will constantly probe that network while wifi is active. You just need to listen for the Probe Requests they send with Wireshark.

If you want to keep track in which networks which device has been, you need to analyze the traffic dump in order to put each device and each SSID into a DB. You can then query the DB for any given device about all the SSIDs it has been connecting with. This will allow you to track them. But there is no tool I know of which automates this.

There's also a nice tutorial for BT/Kali Linux for this: https://blog.rootshell.be/2012/01/12/show-me-your-ssids-ill-tell-who-you-are/

The only way to defend against this is disabling auto-connect on your device, so it stops sending probes randomly when you turn it on. This is also the reason you dont **always** get all past SSIDs from a device, because some devices do not connect automatically or only at certain intervals (which you can miss).

Comment: Example of "wlan.fc.type_subtype==0x04": 

310 13.248289000 Htc_xx:xx:xx Broadcast 802.11 96 Probe Request, SN=76, FN=0, Flags=........C, SSID=Name of the SSID

Comment: I am referring to the fact that some devices (like this HTC) shoot out all known SSID's (ESSID) that they ever been connected.

Comment: Reformatted my post a bit for clarification.

Comment: And i just discovered tshark :)) Thx!